# Why is this not a duplicate symbol error?

Tags: c, xcode, compiler-errors, duplicate-symbol

I have a iOS framework that contains `.c`, `.mm` source files. 
For convenience let's call these two files `A.c` and `B.mm`.

In both files, I defined a function with the same function protocol like the following.

```
// A.c

uint32_t get_file(const char *path)
{
    ...
}

// B.mm

uint32_t get_file(const char *path)
{
    ...
}
```

As far as I know, I thought this would throw an error at compile time because there's duplicate symbol, but it successfully compiles the framework without any error. What am I missing here?

Note: 
This will be a `duplicate symbol` linker error if it was `.c` and `.m` because Objective-C doesn't undergo name mangling.

Comment: Just for the fun of nit-picking. Duplicate symbols in two different compile units would be a linker error, not compile error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objective-C++ files (.mm) are C++ files, so they undergo name mangling. If you run `nm` on the output, you'll see something along the lines of:

```
$ nm a.out | grep get_file
0000000100000fa0 T __Z8get_filePKc
0000000100000f70 T _get_file
```

If you applied `extern "C"` in the C++ version to remove name mangling, you'd see the collision you're expecting:

```
// B.mm
extern "C" uint32_t get_file(const char *path)
{
    return 0;
}


$ clang A.c B.mm
duplicate symbol _get_file in:
    /var/folders/j3/32xftcp56c12hqz7y8rl4f600000gn/T/A-d00e10.o
    /var/folders/j3/32xftcp56c12hqz7y8rl4f600000gn/T/B-d853af.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```